# launching UWP/Desktop bridge exe doesn't work correctly using FullTrustLauncher

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, desktop-bridge

So I was working on a project that needs a .net 3.5 framework API. So since I can't use the API directly I decided to use communication using a bridge between a UWP/WPF app in order to use the API.

Now I have followed the steps in here: https://mtaulty.com/2016/10/12/windows-10-1607-uwp-apps-packaged-with-companion-desktop-apps/

So when launching the app from the exe directly it would work fine. However if I am to launch it it is unable to load the API.

Any idea of what I can do to deal with it? Or is there a better way to implement a .net 3.5 api in UWP?

Why does FullTrustLauncher stop the app from working correctly? Would packaging the APP in something like ILMerge help?

Or are there any ideas I can do to deal with this issue?

Edit: here is the sdk I have been using with its documentation

http://sdk.emiratesid.ae/page/Downloads.aspx

It also contains sample projects in forms however as mention the issues arise when porting to uwp

Comment: Did you try to start the UWP process without the debugger attached to it?

Comment: Can you provide some more details? What API is failing? Is there any exception, error message or callstack you can share? Can you share a simple repro project that we can look at and help you debug the problem? Thanks!

Comment: I will upload an example in a while.

Comment: Please share the sample project. Otherwise we will need to close the question as being unclear. Thanks!

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: Have you debugged the code to see what/where it is failing? When running in a packaged app your code now runs in a different context, for example writes to the install folder are blocked, AppData writes are redirected, registry write are redirected, etc. See here for some more context: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-behind-the-scenes  - the bottom line is that once you package your app you need to test, debug and potentially make some adjustments to the code in order to comply with the app model.